# onclick event needs clicking twice to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have this music player button, which needs to click twice to play it. It should be just clicked once

```
<audio id="audio1" ontimeupdate="updateBar()" src="/musicfile/Kalimba.mp3">
        </audio>
 <span id="audioControl1" onclick="togglePlaying()">
            <i class="fa fa fa-play fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
```

Javascript

```
var audioEl = document.getElementById("audio1")
var ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl1')

function togglePlaying() {
  
  var play = ctrl.innerHTML === '<i class="fa fa fa-play fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
  var method
  
  if (play) {
    ctrl.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa fa-pause fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    method = 'play'
  } else {
    ctrl.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa fa-play fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    method = 'pause'
  }
  
  audioEl[method]()
  
}
```

Comment: We need to see `audioEl`.

Comment: javascript
```
var audioEl = document.getElementById("audio1")
```

html
````
<audio id="audio1" ontimeupdate="updateBar()" src="/musicfile/Kalimba.mp3">
        </audio>
````

Comment: Please edit your question and include that code for better readability. However, you are trying to call a function that would be returned from an Array called `audioEl` with the code `audioEl[method]()` and since `audioEl` is an element, that code seems to be a problem.

Comment: Yes I updated the code. but the play button worked on the second click

Comment: Side-point: setting the `fa` class multiple times is almost certainly redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an older version of font-awesome than me, change fas with fa. I believe this'll absolutely work for you:

```js
var audioEl = document.getElementById("audio1")
var ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl1')

function togglePlaying() {

  var method;
  if (ctrl.getAttribute("action") == "play") {
    method = 'pause';
    musicAction = 'play';
  } else {
    method = 'play';
    musicAction = 'pause';
  }

  ctrl.setAttribute('action',method);
  ctrl.setAttribute('class','fas fa-'+method+' fa-stack-1x fa-inverse');

  audioEl[musicAction]()

}
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Font-Awesome Icon CDN -->

<audio id="audio1" src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-ukulele.mp3"></audio>
<div onclick="togglePlaying()">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i id="audioControl1" action="play" class="fas fa-play fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

And also you cannot use `fa-inverse` without `fa-stack`, if you want to learn why check it out: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

Comment: Do not forget to add `ontimeupdate="updateBar()"` to audio element.

Comment: Btw my code is literally working well but if anyone has any problem with the code about wrong, please send your feedback before/after voting me!

Comment: Changing the class has no bearing on this JavaScript problem. Your code works because you took a completely different approach to deciding whether to play or pause than the OP took.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing html contents. Unfortunately the first time you compare html contents, the html to be compared has spaces (since you have formatted it within its parent element), and the comparison returns false. But, since the html will be replaced by setting `innerHTML` to a new value, the html will from then on have no whitespace, allowing the *next* comparison to work properly.

I recommend avoiding html comparison and `innerHTML` setting altogether; use `classList` instead. Note this is a working example; click to play/pause sound:

```js
var audioEl = document.getElementById("audio1")
var ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl1');
let togglePlaying = () => {
  
  let i = ctrl.querySelector('i');
  i.classList.contains('fa-play')
    ? (i.classList.replace('fa-play', 'fa-pause'), audioEl.play())
    : (i.classList.replace('fa-pause', 'fa-play'), audioEl.pause());
  
}
let updateBar = () => {};
```

```css
i { display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; border-radius: 100%; }
i.fa-play { background-color: rgba(200, 0, 0, 1); }
i.fa-pause { background-color: rgba(0, 150, 0, 1); }
```

```html
<audio id="audio1" ontimeupdate="updateBar()" src="https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-ukulele.mp3"></audio>
<span id="audioControl1" onclick="togglePlaying()">
  <i class="fa fa-play fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original HTML has the `i` element nested within the `span`, but you've included line breaks and spaces for indenting the code. Those whitespace characters become part of the `span` element's `.innerHTML`, so when you do your first check against just the `i` element (all in one line), the test fails, but then sets the `.innerHTML` to just that, so the second test succeeds.

You should strive to avoid `.innerHTML` for many reasons:

- Problems just like this where what the actual `.innerHTML` is isn't
  what you think it is.
- There are security implications to using `.innerHTML`.
- There are performance implications to using `.innerHTML`.

Instead, rely on the classes that the element in question has or doesn't have and adjust them, individually, instead of strings of HTML. Use the `.classList` API to do this very easily.

Also, remember not to try to run your `audio` until you know that it's been completely downloaded to the client. Do this by wrapping that code in a `load` event handler.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var audioEl = document.getElementById("audio1");
  
  document.getElementById('audioControl1').addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Find the <i> element within the clicked <span> element
    var control = this.querySelector("i");
    
    if (control.classList.contains("fa-play")) {
      control.classList.remove("fa-play");
      control.classList.add("fa-pause");
      control.textContent = "Pause"; // Just for testing here
      audioEl.play();
    } else {
      control.classList.add("fa-play");
      control.classList.remove("fa-pause");
      control.textContent = "Pause"; // Just for testing here
      audioEl.pause();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="audio1" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>

  <span id="audioControl1">
    <i class="fa fa-play fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true">play</i>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend silently preventing play/pause functionality before the file is loaded; if anything some visual change in the dom should be connected to the load event

Comment: @Gershom I'm not necessarily recommending that. I'm just saying don't attempt to play something until you know it's there.